# JOOQ alias construction

Tags: java, jooq

We use JOOQ 3.7.2 and it seems that JOOQ calculates different hashcodes for same query if it contains different values of bind parameters and as a result parts of query has different alias if execute with different input

In our code we use construction `asTable`, and JOOQ construct alias name like

```
public final Table<R> asTable() {
    return (new DerivedTable(this)).as("alias_" + Utils.hash(this));
}
```

and hash code calculates from org.jooq.impl.AbstractQueryPart

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    // This is a working default implementation. It should be overridden by
    // concrete subclasses, to improve performance

    return create().renderInlined(this).hashCode();
}
```

`renderInlined(this)` is different for the same query with different input values. For example

```
where rownum = 1
    order by MYFIELD asc
  ) alias_132316169
) alias_55254251
```

and

```
where rownum = 2
    order by MYFIELD asc
  ) alias_117501160
) alias_82323306
```

Value for check rownum equality is bind variable

Is it possible to produce same alias code for query with bind variables? Because now JOOQ generates different aliases and it is cause of problem for Oracle query cache

Or may be there another approach exists.

### Example

Lets create table

```
create table JOOQ_TEST (id number, val varchar2(100))
```

and run next code

```
@Test
public void testSelect() throws Exception {
    List<Long> ids = new ArrayList<Long>();
    ids.add(1L);
    ids.add(2L);

    for (Long i : ids) {
        Table table = dsl.select(JOOQ_TEST.VAL, JOOQ_TEST.ID)
                .from(JOOQ_TEST)
                .where(JOOQ_TEST.ID.eq(i))
                .orderBy(JOOQ_TEST.ID).asTable();

        dsl.select().from(table).fetch();
    }
}
```

and we got

```
2017-04-28 17:37:58,235 DEBUG [main] org.jooq.tools.LoggerListener Executing query          : 
select 
  alias_116981037.VAL, 
  alias_116981037.ID
from (
  select 
    JOOQ_TEST.VAL, 
    JOOQ_TEST.ID
  from JOOQ_TEST
  where JOOQ_TEST.ID = ?
  order by JOOQ_TEST.ID asc
) alias_116981037
2017-04-28 17:37:58,236 DEBUG [main] org.jooq.tools.LoggerListener -> with bind values      : 
select 
  alias_116981037.VAL, 
  alias_116981037.ID
from (
  select 
    JOOQ_TEST.VAL, 
    JOOQ_TEST.ID
  from JOOQ_TEST
  where JOOQ_TEST.ID = 1
  order by JOOQ_TEST.ID asc
) alias_116981037
2017-04-28 17:37:58,593 DEBUG [main] org.jooq.tools.StopWatch Query executed           : Total: 361.112ms
2017-04-28 17:37:58,613 DEBUG [main] org.jooq.tools.LoggerListener Fetched result           : +----+----+
2017-04-28 17:37:58,613 DEBUG [main] org.jooq.tools.LoggerListener                          : |VAL |  ID|
2017-04-28 17:37:58,613 DEBUG [main] org.jooq.tools.LoggerListener                          : +----+----+
2017-04-28 17:37:58,613 DEBUG [main] org.jooq.tools.StopWatch Finishing                : Total: 381.65ms, +20.538ms
2017-04-28 17:37:58,614 DEBUG [main] org.jooq.tools.LoggerListener Executing query          : 
select 
  alias_4853230.VAL, 
  alias_4853230.ID
from (
  select 
    JOOQ_TEST.VAL, 
    JOOQ_TEST.ID
  from JOOQ_TEST
  where JOOQ_TEST.ID = ?
  order by JOOQ_TEST.ID asc
) alias_4853230
2017-04-28 17:37:58,615 DEBUG [main] org.jooq.tools.LoggerListener -> with bind values      : 
select 
  alias_4853230.VAL, 
  alias_4853230.ID
from (
  select 
    JOOQ_TEST.VAL, 
    JOOQ_TEST.ID
  from JOOQ_TEST
  where JOOQ_TEST.ID = 2
  order by JOOQ_TEST.ID asc
) alias_4853230
2017-04-28 17:37:58,633 DEBUG [main] org.jooq.tools.StopWatch Query executed           : Total: 18.899ms
2017-04-28 17:37:58,637 DEBUG [main] org.jooq.tools.LoggerListener Fetched result           : +----+----+
2017-04-28 17:37:58,638 DEBUG [main] org.jooq.tools.LoggerListener                          : |VAL |  ID|
2017-04-28 17:37:58,638 DEBUG [main] org.jooq.tools.LoggerListener                          : +----+----+
2017-04-28 17:37:58,638 DEBUG [main] org.jooq.tools.StopWatch Finishing                : Total: 23.931ms, +5.031ms
```

Comment: What is the relationship between the JOOQ hash code and the Oracle query cache? How does Oracle get to see the hash code? Does it become part of the query string somehow?

Comment: yes, it produce value for alias `.as("alias_" + Utils.hash(this))` and alias become part of query

Comment: Can you manually assign a different (stable and meaningful) alias for that derived table? There is a method `asTable("betterAlias")` I believe.

Comment: I can, but may be there is way how to configure it properly

Comment: yes, I just added it, may be it a bit artifical, but aliases are different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug ([#6025](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6025)). The generated SQL string (as well as the `Query.equals()` and `Query.hashCode()` behaviour) should be stable, regardless of your concrete bind variables.

As a workaround, you can specify an explicit table alias rather than letting jOOQ generate one for you:

```java
Table table = dsl.select(JOOQ_TEST.VAL, JOOQ_TEST.ID)
                 .from(JOOQ_TEST)
                 .where(JOOQ_TEST.ID.eq(i))
                 .orderBy(JOOQ_TEST.ID).asTable("t"); // table alias here
```